# HTTP redirect does not work in every browser

Tags: java, firefox, network-programming, brave-browser

I am running an HTTP-Server with a `ServerSocket` and listening for `Socket's` that the server accepts. I want to redirect to an external site depending the request. So far I parse the request and write the response into the `OutputStream` of the client `Socket`.
Running the following example code:

```
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
os.write("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("Location: http://www.google.com/\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
os.flush();
clientSocket.close();
```

The redirection to `google.com` works in firefox but in brave browser it opens a new browser window (without actually navigating to the site) after notifying me with "Open xdg-open? A website wants to open this application". I am running the browser on Arch Linux. How can I make it work for brave browser as well?

Comment: maybe a stupid question from my side, why are there 2 time eol ? os.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes()); maybe 1 should work? os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by sgpalit in the comments, the response should be ended by a single EOL instead of one. This apparently induced the strange behavior. Changing `os.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());` to `os.write("\r\n".getBytes());` solved the problem.